# Не срабатывает RewriteRule

Tags: yii2, .htaccess

Установил yii2-basic шаблон.

В корне сайта .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Однако, когда страница загружаются, она грузится без стилей. 
Допустим файл лежит http://ex.com/web/css/site.css.
Но почему-то по ссылке http://ex.com/css/site.css он выдает ошибку 404.

Answer (score 0):

У вас document root уже находится  /web.
Не нужно ничего дополнительно перенаправлять в htaccess.

Comment: document root направлен на htdocs

Comment: Направьте его на web. И ничего дописывать в  htaccess дополнительно не нужно тк работает из стандартной сборки все.

Comment: Т.е. без конфигурации апач работать не будет?